# Steam and OpenGl 4.1

Tags: games, steam, opengl

When I heard Saints Row 4 is now compatible with SteamOS I had to jump right on it but when I finished installing and then tried to run the game, I got this error message. Does anyone know how I can fix this?[image]

Comment: What graphics card and driver version?

Comment: If you want to fix it, implement OpenGL support for that GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes down to what graphics driver you have installed. By default, Ubuntu will install a driver based on Mesa, which does not support OpenGL 4.1. To get full support, you need to install a proprietary driver for your GPU.

With that being said, you will have to install the proper driver yourself. Check here: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

or simply:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that **restart** your computer. Try launching the game again. It should work!

Comment: What do I do if this didn't work? I have an NVidia 630M

Comment: I concur. I've installed the PPA, but glxinfo still reports "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.3.0-devel" and Saints Row 4 still reports the same dialog as the OP showed. I have an HD 6850 which should support OpenGL 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ppa for OpenGL 4.1 :

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers