# Black Menus and terminal window after graphics driver install 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam, opengl

I am running a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (alongside Windows 10) on a brand new(ish) Toshiba laptop. Everything was working fine until I installed Bioshock Infinite from Steam and when I ran it I got an error saying that my graphics driver did not support OpenGL 4.1. My graphics card is Nvidia 930M.

So I did a search and found this post: [Steam and OpenGl 4.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713586/steam-and-opengl-4-1). I followed the instructions there and installed the repository ppa: `oibaf/graphics-drivers.`

After the restart all menus were simply black rectangles, the Terminal window was completely black and there were large black borders around windows. This problem appears on several other posts. I followed all of the instructions in these (such as remove Nvidia and reinstall, remove the above repository, etc.). But to no avail. I am also surprised how little help this problem has received from the community. (See for example: [Black border in all menus and black terminal after installing Katoolin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788882/black-border-in-all-menus-and-black-terminal-arfter-installing-katoolin)).

Answer (score 2):

I am happy to say that by installing the latest Nvidia drivers I solved the problem. Here's what I did.

I followed the instructions from [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus) to find and install the latest driver for Nvidia.

I then went into `system settings -> software&updates -> additional drivers` and selected the latest proprietary Nvidia driver I just installed and clicked *apply changes*. At this point a black dialog box comes up asking for your password. Just blindly enter your password and press *enter*. Then restart.